# Mysql query help to display results less than given date

Tags: mysql

I am having my date field in `Mysql` which is stored as `char` is as follows `050712`.. Now I would like to display the results which are available in the database which are less than this date. I write as follows

Condition should fail

```
select * from tblFedACHRDFI where date_format(changedate,'%m/%d/%Y')> 05/08/12;
```

This is displaying all records which are available but I don't need that I would like to display only when date is `05/06/12` which means

True Condition

```
select * from tblFedACHRDFI where date_format(changedate,'%m/%d/%Y')> 05/06/12;
```

The same worked for me in `Sqlserver` when I write as follows

Records not getting displayed which is true as per my requirement

```
select * from tblFedACHRDFI where
 CONVERT(datetime,(SUBSTRING(ChangeDate,1,2)+'/'
+SUBSTRING(ChangeDate,3,2)+'/'+dbo.Years
(SUBSTRING(ChangeDate,5,2))+SUBSTRING(ChangeDate,5,2)))>
 '05/08/2012'
```

So can any one help me where I went wrong in `MySql` statement..

Comment: That's a bad way to store dates in MySQL. If you can, switch to `DATE` instead of `CHAR`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A MySQL date should be YYYY-MM-DD, column type should be DATE.

If you wish to store a date any other way (for example, a CHAR(6) as you do here), you'll have to use conversions each time you use the date. This is slower, uses more CPU, and can fail because you can store invalid values in your CHAR field.

It does work, however. Use the [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert your CHAR column to a proper date. Now you can compare it against a proper date, use INTERVAL functions, the whole shebang:

```
select * 
from tblFedACHRDFI 
where str_to_date(changedate,'%m%d%Y') > "2012-08-05";
```

Comment: But I am unable to get records if i enter date as `2012-06-05`

Comment: What do you mean, `if I enter date as 2012-06-05`? Your `changedate` is a CHAR(6), right? Storing 2 digits for each month,day,year? Well, use STR_TO_DATE to have MySQL convert it to a proper DATE, then you can use that proper date for what you need (in the example, later than august 5th).

Comment: My records are available only till `may 07 2012` so my record should be displayed if i enter `may 06 2012` i.e `2012-06-05`

Comment: Well, it will: `select str_to_date("050712",'%m%d%Y') > "2012-08-05";` gives 0 and `select str_to_date("050712",'%m%d%Y') > "2012-05-05";` gives 1. See?

Comment: This works but how can I convert the date `mm/dd/yyyy` to `YYYY-mm-dd` inside mysql is it possible

Comment: As I said, use the STR_TO_DATE function! Did you read the documentation? `SELECT str_to_date("05/13/12",'%m/%d/%y')` gives 2012-05-13. Please, [go read the documentation first](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), edit your question with what you do not understand then.